# How can i use this class on more than one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**SCRIPT AND HTML CODE:** When i click on a button, the other buttons are working. I've one class for buttons so how can i use multiple this button ?
Shall i add data_id for each button ?

Comment: What *"other buttons"*? What do you even mean by *"Shall i add data_id for each button"*? This question makes very little sense and I don't see a link between what you're asking and the code

Comment: Use the event.target. Like function play(event){ event.target.addClass('play')}

Comment: Ohh, sorry i have to say class. I've music page and when i click one class (button) the other classes are working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4160.mp3" id="audio" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new class to the  tag. And get the element on your JQuery by the new class, like this:

```js
    function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
             $('.play-button').addClass('icon-control-pause')
            $('.play-button').removeClass('icon-control-play')
                  
        }else{
            audio.pause();
            $('.play-button').addClass('icon-control-play')
            $('.play-button').removeClass('icon-control-pause')

  
        }
    }
```

```html
 

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
   <audio src="audio.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
<i class="play-button icon-control-play i-2x" id="play" onclick="play()"></i>
```